# What is assignment via curly braces called? and can it be controlled?

Tags: c++

What is this called?

```
Vec3 foo = {1,2,3};
```

Can it be controlled via an operator or some such? As in can I specify how this should act?

For instance if I had some complicated class could I use this to assign variables? (Just an exercise in curiosity).

Comment: I don't feel like writing this up or finding a duplicate, but in C++11, in contrast to Nawaz's excellent answer, that syntax is can be caught by initializer list constructors, and it can indeed be used for assignment by using it to initialize a temporary. http://ideone.com/RwLop

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That is not assignment. That is initialization.

Such initialization is allowed for aggregate only, that includes POD class. POD means Plain Old Data type.

Example,

```
//this struct is an aggregate (POD class)
struct point3D
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
};

//since point3D is an aggregate, so we can initialize it as
point3D p = {1,2,3};
```

See the above compiles fine : http://ideone.com/IXcSA

But again consider this:

```
//this struct is NOT an aggregate (non-POD class)
struct vector3D
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
   vector3D(int, int, int){} //user-defined constructor!
};

//since vector3D is NOT an aggregate, so we CANNOT initialize it as
vector3D p = {1,2,3}; //error
```

The above does NOT compile. It gives this error:

> prog.cpp:15: error: braces around initializer for non-aggregate type ‘vector3D’

See yourself : http://ideone.com/zO58c

What is the difference between `point3D` and `vector3D`? Just the `vector3D` has user-defined constructor, and that makes it non-POD. Hence it cannot be initialized using curly braces!

---

## What is an aggregate?

The Standard says in section §8.5.1/1,

> An aggregate is **an array or a class**
>   (clause 9) with **no user-declared
>   constructors** (12.1), **no private or
>   protected non-static data members**
>   (clause 11), **no base classes** (clause
>   10), and **no virtual functions** (10.3).

And then it says in §8.5.1/2 that,

> When an aggregate is initialized the
>   initializer can contain an
>   initializer-clause consisting of a
>   brace-enclosed, comma-separated list of
>   initializer-clauses for the members of
>   the aggregate, written in increasing
>   subscript or member order. If the
>   aggregate contains subaggregates, this
>   rule applies recursively to the
>   members of the subaggregate.

```
[Example:

struct A 
{
   int x;
   struct B 
   {
      int i;
      int j;
   } b;
} a = { 1, { 2, 3 } };

initializes a.x with 1, a.b.i with 2, a.b.j with 3. ]
```

Comment: You say that it's POD-only, but your compiler complains about non-aggregate. So, can an aggregate class which is not POD be initialized in this way? Yes it can.

Comment: You should also give an example that uses arrays.

Comment: This is good, but it would be nice if you at least mentioned C++11 initialization syntax. ;-)

Comment: Do you know, is there any difference between following two statements:

std::vector<int> data {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> data = {1, 2, 3};

Comment: @MeJ: Practically, no difference. Pedantically, first one is direct initialization and the second one is copy initialization.

Comment: But both calls the sequence constructor, because the sequence constructor has a higher priority as the copy constructor, true?

Comment: Compiles fine with MSVC2013, btw (must be MS changing the rules again).

Comment: vector3D p = {1,2,3}; compiles fine for me

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly and briefly.

The assignment via curly braces is called "direct assignment" and it has its own rules.

> If the right operand is a braced-init-list
>
> if the expression E1 has scalar type, the expression E1 = {} is equivalent to E1 = T{}, where T is the type of E1. the expression E1 =
> {E2} is equivalent to E1 = T{E2}, where T is the type of E1.

> if the
> expression E1 has class type, the syntax E1 = {args...} generates a
> call to the assignment operator with the braced-init-list as the
> argument, which then selects the appropriate assignment operator
> following the rules of overload resolution. Note that, if a
> non-template assignment operator from some non-class type is
> available, it is preferred over the copy/move assignment in E1 = {}
> because {} to non-class is an identity conversion, which outranks the
> user-defined conversion from {} to a class type.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment