# C++ static_cast<void *>

Tags: c++, static-cast

Could someone explain this little code snippet for me?

Given:

```
int a[3] = {2,3,4};
```

Why does the following evaluate to true?

```
static_cast<void *>(a) == static_cast<void *>(&a); // Why is this true?
```

Is this saying that the `address of a` is the same as `a`? If so, why is this true?

Comment: It probably looks weird if you are new to C/C++.  It's actually a convention left-over from C : it only applies to literal arrays (and I think function names/pointers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because address of the variable `a` concides with the address of the first element of array `a`. You can also think of `a` is `&a[0]` which is clearer when we say "the address of the first element of the array").

Another example,

```
struct X
{
    int i;
};

X x;
```

Here also the address of variable `x` concides with the address of `x.i` (which is the first element of the aggregate), so this would print `1`:

```
std::cout << (&x == &(x.i)) << std::endl; //1
```

So in your case, `&a` is like `&x`, and `a` (or `&a[0]`) is like `&(x.i)`.

Note that in C++ `a` and `x` are both called aggregate (see my answer here: [What is an aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666321/what-is-assignment-via-curly-braces-called-and-can-it-be-controlled))

Comment: Hmm, so I understand that `a == &a[0]` does exactly this. In this case I thought we were de-refrencing (is this correct term?) to the 0th position in the array `a`, and then taking the address of that position, which is what is pointed to by `a` in the first place. But in the case of the original post I thought we would be comparing `a`, which is a pointer that stores an address to the first element of the array, to the address of this pointer `a`. Does this mean on the stack there is no actual local variable `a` that points to an an array on the stack?

Comment: (continued) How is this array handled on the stack? Maybe this will help to make it more clear to me.

Comment: @tdashroy: There is an actual local variable `a`, which is just the beginning of the array. The stack-space occupied by `a`  is equal to `sizeof(a)` bytes, which is same as `sizeof(ElementType) * ElementCount`.

Comment: ohhhh...okay. I thought there would be a pointer `a` to some place on the stack which would be the beginning of the array. So just to be clear (sorry, last question I promise!), this is how it works for dynamic arrays, which is why the same line doesn't evaluate to true for them?

Comment: @tdashroy: For dynamic array, say `int *b = new int[100]`, only the pointer is put on the stack (which takes usually `4` or `8` bytes, depending on the size of the pointer), and the elements reside somewhere else whose address is stored in the pointer `b`. In this case, `&b` and `b` are not same, though `b` and `&b[0]` are same!

Answer (score 1):

In almost all contexts, the name of an array decays into a pointer to the first element of the array. So in `static_cast<void*>(a)`, the `a` decays into `&a[0]`; it's type is "pointer to int". The expression evaluates to the address of the first element of the array. In `static_cast<void*>(&a)`, however, `&a` is the address of the array itself; its type is "pointer to array of 3 int". That's why the casts are needed here: the two expressions without the casts would have different types, and could not be compared. Both can be converted to `void*` and compared. So what this code is illustrating is that the address of the first element of an array is the same as the address of the array, *i.e.*, there's no padding at the front.

Answer (score 0):

The name of an array usually evaluates to the address of the first element of the array, so array and &array have exact the same value.

However, they are different types. For the following array:

```
int a[8];
```

a+1 is the address of the array a + sizeof(int)
but &a+1 will be the address of the array a + 8 * sizeof(int).