# what is a brace-or-equals initializer?

Tags: c++, initializer

I know this question is simple, but it is so simple I have found no resources defining me what is a "brace-or-equals".

Are those all brace-or-equals initializer?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
int foo= 42;

int foo{42};

int foo= {42};

int foo[]{41,42,43};

int foo[]={41,42,43};

struct Foo{
    int data= 42;
};
```

Considering the aformentioned structure, with `data` initialized **or not**, in both cases:

```
Foo foo{42}
Foo foo= {42}
Foo foo{.data=42}
Foo foo= {.data=42}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Some possible duplicate targets: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666321/what-is-assignment-via-curly-braces-called-and-can-it-be-controlled) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601201/c-struct-initialization-using-labels-it-works-but-how).

Comment: (next time please only ask 1 question in a post. The other one is GCC's language extension, not standard C++)

Comment: user202729, You mean the last examples? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
This looks like  standard c++
Also the stackoverflow link you've given doesn't use the words "brace-or-equals"

Comment: *"(since C++20)"*

Comment: Well, indeed it is not yet official. I only put those with the intention of being exhaustive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's literally what it says on the tin: an initializer of the form `= something` ("equals") or `{ something }` ("brace"). In other words, it excludes the `( something )` form of initializers.

The name comes from the grammar nonterminal for the construct.